# Docker entrypoint initdb PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, relational-database

I am getting the following error when I run docker-compose up:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this problem by adding this to the Dockerfile after it copies the scripts to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

```
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**Example Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE NAME_DATABASE
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD ***********

COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"]
```

The next step is to build the image:

```
docker build -t image-db:latest .
```

The next step is to create the container

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name container-db  image-db:latest
```

Comment: How to change permissions if the file is initialized from docker compose?

Comment: Found a solution, simply `chmod -R 777 /config/folder` fixes the issue. Where `config/folder` is where mysql scripts are located.

Comment: @AnisBenna. Always sceptical of setting 777. For me it was enough to set 755.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, however, my problem occurred due to Linux user. I am using root as a runner so the problem happened because the mounting volume in the local machine did not have permissions. in this regard, I used `chmod -R 777 scripts` and it worked fine. Technically, you need to set permissions for both local machine and your container.

Answer (score 3):

You should not override the postgres image entrypoint. It is designed to look for `.sql` files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory (See [line in script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/14f13e4b399ed1848fa24c2c1f5bd40c25732bdd/13/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L307)).

You should just mount your `.sql` files into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and it should be processed on startup (only if database does not already exist)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gcharbon. I updated the post and i get a permission denied error when I run docker compose up. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not use shell scripts to bootstrap your database.
You're using an `alpine` image which does not have `bash` installed.
So remove the volume mounting a shell script, and simply mount `.sql` files into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @gcharbon. I solved it after I entered the container with bash by changing the permissions of the file init-db.sh to 755. Now when I run docker compose up it successfully initialises the db.

Comment: the question mentions not able to run the /bin/bash script interpreter. however google sends me here for a generic permission denied when I simply cat the file. in my case, it was caused by SELinux, which is fixed by appending :Z to the volume bind mount argument (for example, -v /srv/containers/db1dev/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:Z)